# LinqPad / Sqlite version info and foreign key support

Tags: sqlite, linqpad

I am using fabulous LinqPad and its Sqlite driver.

1) Is there a way to obtain Sqlite version information by executing say "select version"?

2) Which driver specific connection string should I use to enable foreign key support in Sqlite?

Comment: Ok, I have just found out about 2) myself. It appears for Sqlite, System.Data.SQLite is used which is currently at version 1.0.65.0 and thus knows nothing about foreign keys in Sqlite. Therefore, there is nothing in the connection string that would make it use foreign key enforcement.

Question 1) is still open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select distinct sqlite_version() from sqlite_master;`

Comment: Brilliant! Way to go! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

1) `select sqlite_version()`

2) on http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/2159/8788.aspx they say the connection string parameter is `EnforceFKConstraints`, the SQLite documentation isn't as browsable as I would like it to be :/

Comment: 1) Thanks, but that's hardly SQL, is it?

2) Great, but the author's comment is 3 months old and the latest released version is over 8 months old. Once it's finally released it will be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I left out my feelings about SQLite on purpose; perhaps there are elegant solutions available, finding the syntax is the real challenge :P